# AdMob sdk error linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, admob

I am testing latest Ad Mob in my app using X CODE 4.3, but it gives me "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" error

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: `Project -> Build Settings -> remove the architecture from "valid architectures".`

Comment: i removed armv6 and armv 7 from the row but still same error

Comment: add `AdSupport.framework`. Also remember to remove `-all_load linker flag`

Comment: can't add AdSupport.framework because i am using xcode 4.3

Comment: http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.in/2012/09/migrating-to-admob-v62-for-ios.html